# 404 error Sharepoint 2010 accessing Lists.asmx

Tags: web-services, iis-7, sharepoint-2010

When attempting to checkout a document I receive the following message

"This document could not be checked out. You may not have permission..." etc etc

So I used Fiddler and discovered that the REAL error was a 404 when Sharepoint attempts to access the Lists.asmx url. I am assuming it uses the webservice to perform checkout.

The Sharepoint is set up under IIS for https or SSL. Another test farm I put together without SSL does not have issues getting to it's web service.

Another curiousity is that there was no issue checking a document out when the SHAREPOINT OPENDOCUMENTS CLASS add on in the browser is turned off.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was stumped on a 404 error as well while communicating with Sharepoint, but it was when I was calling GetListCollection(). It turned out to be because the default behavior for GetListCollection() is to return all of the lists from the rootweb. To filter it more specifically change the .Url property to point to a list.asmx lower down the site (regardless of where you set your initial reference).

For example:

```
ListsWS.Lists lws = new ListsWS.Lists();
lws.Url = "http://server/sites/someSubSite/_vti_bin/lists.asmx";
```